# Clean up LaunchAgents on Uninstall

Tags: macos, cocoa, launchd

I have a LaunchAgent in my Mac OSX app.
How do I clean up the Launch Agent plist file when a User drags my app into the trash to uninstall?
Can I make a symbolic link to a plist file in my bundle or something like that?

Comment: Though it sucks, you're basically on your own in this scenario. Trashing an app bundle has no system hooks to notify an uninstall script, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joshua Nozzi commented, there's no way to be notified when the user trashes your app. That doesn't completely shut you out of cleaning up launchd tasks, though. If any of those tasks run an executable or shell script outside of your app (if not, they could), said script can check to see whether the app is still installed and unschefule/delete itself if not.

Comment: Where would be the standard location on macOs to put the script that checks if your app is still present or not? (i.e. a location not within your app)